# angularjs hide ui-view on certain state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui

I have controller and template views of that controllers.

- ProductCtrl => Products.html
- SomeCrtl => Some.html
- FooCtrl => Foo.html

I have a **ui-view** on home page.

```
<html> 
   <body> 
     <a href="#/product"></a>
     <a href="#/some"></a>
     <a href="#/foo"></a>
     <div ui-view></div> 
       ....
```

State config like this:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("product", {
        url: "/product",
        templateUrl: "templates/Products.html",
        controller: "ProductCtrl"
    });
}])
```

My last view is appearing on **ui-view** when application  started. But I want that **ui-view** should be empty. When I click a link then should view that content.

Comment: You just have to NOT map the `/` url to a state.

Comment: I updated with state. I removed "/" from url but link did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your `ui-view` with an HTML element, and manipulate hide it using `ng-hide` depending on the current state.

Code sample

```
<div ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'home'">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what @bookmarker mentioned:

```
<div ng-hide="$state.includes('home')">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

`$state.includes('...')` can be used to see if a state contains a specified state, that is, check if a child state contains a certain parent state.